# Update command gets executed but doesn't change anything

Tags: c#, sql

```
if (n != true)
{
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("select max(Angebotsnummer) from tbl_Angebote", con);
    neue_nr = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into tbl_Angebote values(@nr,@knr, @date, @bet)", con);
}
else
{
    neue_nr = Convert.ToInt32(txtAngebotsnummer.Text);
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("update tbl_Angebote set Kundennummer=@knr, Erstellungsdatum=@date, Betreff=@bet where Angebotsnummer=@nr", con);
}

cmd.Parameters.Add("@nr", OleDbType.Char, 10);
cmd.Parameters["@nr"].Value = neue_nr;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@knr", OleDbType.Char, 50);
cmd.Parameters["@knr"].Value = Convert.ToString(txtKnr.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date, 50);
cmd.Parameters["@date"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDatum.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@bet", OleDbType.Char, 255);
cmd.Parameters["@bet"].Value = Convert.ToString(txtBetreff.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Insert command is working, the update command isn't...

If I put the same command in Access, it works.

What's wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OleDbCommand` does not actually take named parameters. So the order in which the parameters occur in the query, need to be the same as the order you add the parameters to your command.

So in your case, for the update command, the value of the last parameter `@bet` is being used for the where clause. Try re-ordering the parameters in the queries so they match in both queries so you don't have to duplicate the code that adds the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

run your updated in SQL and check if it's updating or not?

```
update tbl_Angebote set Kundennummer='@knr', Erstellungsdatum='@date',
Betreff='@bet' where Angebotsnummer='value of @nr'
```

If it works fine and update the table then check the data type and length of your parameter @nr.